# Asp.net mvc controller constructor returning error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The constructor for this controller is returning the error "} expected". Visual studio is not recognizing it as a constructor. Other errors include "method must have a return type".

What is wrong with this code?

```
namespace blahblah.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {  
        private IUserRepository userRepository;

        public HomeController()
        {     //} expected here
            public Model1Container db = new Model1Container();
            this.userRepository = new UserRepository(db);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
             return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor should look like this:

```
public HomeController()
{   
    Model1Container db = new Model1Container();
    this.userRepository = new UserRepository(db);
}
```

Remove word `public` near the local variable `db`. Access modifiers are not accessible with local variables, as their scope is limited to the method body where they're declared.

From C# language specification 4.0:

> A local variable declaration specifies a type name, a variable name,
>   and possibly an initial value.